# swift iOS8: perform segue after TouchID authentication

Tags: asynchronous, swift, ios8, segue, touch-id

I have a simple App with two views. As soon as the first view is loaded I'm performing a Touch ID sensor authentication (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464628/how-to-use-touchid-using-swift) question):

```
func testTouchID()
{
  if touchIDContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error:&touchIDError) 
  {
    touchIDContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if success 
      {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSecondView", sender: self)
        return;
} else {
```

With this code the segue is performed, but the second view just appears for a moment and then the App goes back to the first view.
It seems that the code inside **canEvalutePolicy** is not finished, so the navigation controller push the first view.

I tried several things like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock
```

And also a combinations of these method, but I'm not able to perform the segue to the second view and stay in the second view.

Can anyone help?

Thanks and best,
Guido

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue. The problem was the navigation controller.

My solution: the first view is not anymore embedded in a navigation controller, it just have a segue to a second view.

Then the second view is embedded in a navigation controller (along with others views) in order to have the navigation behaviour between views that I want.

Important is to use **dispatch_async** in order to "load" the navigation controller as soon as the user authenticates:

```
if success {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("xxx", sender: self)
```

Without dispatch_async the second view appears but the navigation logic of the navigation controller is missing for around 15 seconds.